# SSRS cannot linked text box with field

Tags: ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

I group my table by 3 attributes, and set page break on every group, and now i want to display that three attribute outside the table. I want to place them on the top of the report, and when i type the expression and i go in run view it's display only the first value, when i go to the next page nothing change
I tried to drag field from table, from data set, and nothing working.
In expression i type
 **=Fields!My_Field.Value**.
Also if some of that three attributes i placed in table it normally displays values, but when i try to move it somewhere it stops displaying.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that a **table** is associated with a dataset but a **text box** is not.

You can reference a field from a text box using the Dataset field ( **=Sum(Fields!AMOUNT.Value, "Dataset1")** ) but you need to use an aggregate function like First, Last, or SUM.

It sounds like you don't want to use an aggregate since you are grouping by these fields, though.

> display the three attribute outside the table

If your trying to display the current grouping in the table at the top of each page, add a new Row in your matrix above your header row and add your group fields there.

Comment: thank you very much, i success to find function that you mention and to solve problem.